# How to set website availability based on time (htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess

is it possible to set a time period in the.htaccess file for the availability of website. i.e if a user visits the website from 8am to 10pm IST , the website loads normally. but if the user visits the website between 10:01 pm to 7:59 am the user gets redirected to some other URL...

Comment: Easy in PHP.....

Comment: may be the easiest thing, but dont know how to do that. :(

Comment: Did you give up? You have 3 answers.

Comment: @AbraCadaver i have 3 answers, but only 1 related to the requirement, unfortunately its not working. :(

Comment: So customarily you would give input on those answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this scenario and adjust it as you like :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} ^22$
RewriteCond %{TIME_MIN} !^00$
RewriteRule !^night  /night.php [L,R]

# the lines above will capture from 22:01 up to 22:59 
# and exclude 22:00

RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} ^(23|0[0-7])$
RewriteCond %{TIME_MIN} ^([0-5][0-9])$  
RewriteRule !^night  /night.php [L,R]

# The lines above will capture from 23:00 up to 07:59
```

So, the website between `08:00 AM`  & `22:00 PM` will work as normal .

**Note:** clear browser cache the test

Answer (score 0):

Someone may have a `.htaccess` solution, but an easy one in PHP:

```
if(date('Hi') < 800 || date('Hi') > 2200) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com');
    exit;
}
```